# Ways to step through features without Browse Features from data reviewer extension or data driven pages?

Tags: arcmap, extensions, toolbar

I'm looking for ways to browse through a bunch of points that I have so that I can assign each of them a value. Ideally I would like to be able to use a button on the keyboard to step through each individual point (while keeping the same zoom level) so that I can keep my cursor over my attribute table in order to assign a value to the point. I have used Browse Features before and I know that is an obvious solution but I currently do not have the extension. Data driven pages does work, but it doesn't select the feature so it is easy to get lost where I am when I am in the table when I go to assign a point. I also have to move my cursor to click next page which is slow and clunky and I can't seem to assign a keyboard shortcut to it as well. It also doesn't seem to update the value in the drop down menu to what I have assigned to the name field so I can't keep track of where I am in the table with that either.

Does anyone have any ideas? Being able to stay zoomed in is also important since I need to be able to see the color of the pixel from my imagery that my point is sitting on top of.

Answer (score 2):

As you already have your attribute table open and are editing your attributes in there you can double click on the far left:

[image]

The first click will select the row, the 2nd pans to the selected row if it's a point and zooms to the feature if it is a polygon or line feature class.

This should speed you up as you're not moving your mouse outside the attribute table.

Another suggestion is to hide fields using the layers properties, fields tab (uncheck any fields that you're not interested in *right now*). You can also reorder fields by dragging the column header so that the field(s) you're interested in are closest to the left minimizing mouse movement. Neither of these affect the physical storage of the feature class - all the fields will *still* be there and in the same order.

Answer (score 0):

Welcome Noah!

I created data driven pages from buffer of points of interest. Used Definition Query - Page Definition (match), start editing point layer and open it's attribute table:

[image]

When I click next page (note you can assign keyboard shortcut to it) I see record for relevant point:

[image]

It seems DDP is a way to go. I use it all the time to shuffle through features.

Answer (score 0):

While staying on attribute table, Select a record and use **Ctrl**+**Enter** to select the next record below it and use **Ctrl**+**=**(Equal To button) to zoom to selected record. Through this you can view your record on the data view screen and insert value in the attribute easy.

[image]

For Reference: [Link](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/manage-data/tables/keyboard-shortcuts-for-working-with-tables.htm)